# Conversion source 1.7 and source < 1.7 in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I've made some utilities which I can use in several applications I'm making. The most of the applications support source 1.7, but some of them don't (for example, Android applications).

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String s = "hi";
switch (s) {
    case "hi":
```

For example, diamond operators and switching over strings are not supported in a Java version below 1.7.

I want the source code to be converted to be compatible with a source below 1.7 when I build an Eclipse or Netbeans project.

Can I achieve that? If yes, how? If not, then what should I do instead? Manually replace all source code to 1.6-compatible?

Comment: You can change the `minor_version` and `major_version` in [ClassFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1) by a hex-editor. But it is dangerous and not always working.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this is not possible.

You can do cross-compilation but:

> javac does not accept a target (or compilation strategy) lower than
>   the source language it is configured to accept.

https://blogs.oracle.com/abuckley/entry/versioning_in_the_java_platform

The article is from 2009, but I doubt that this changed with Java SE 7.

Solution:
Use the syntax (source) of the minimal Java version you want to support.

Use a continuous integration server such as Jenkins and configure a Job per JDK you want to support (no need for cross-compilation which might compile but fail at runtime because you used some APIs which are not available in older Java versions.)

Also note: Oracle's Java SE 6 has reach End of Life and it's recommended to update to Java SE 7 in most situations (e.g. when you don't have support contracts with Oracle).

Comment: Some of us don't have a choice.  We're in corporate or government environments that have no intention of moving to Java 7 until forced to.  Especially with all of the Java 7  security problems.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - I think you would find that many / most  of those Java 7 security problems are also Java 6 security problems.  For instance the last four Java 7 security releases were mirrored by Java 6 security releases.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I achieve that?

In theory yes.

> If yes, how?

Use a Java 7 -> Java 6 source code translator.  However, I've not heard of the existence of such a translator ...

> If not, then what should I do instead?  Manually replace all source code to 1.6-compatible?

This is the most practical approach, unless you can find a translator that someone else has implemented.